# Don't upload to aws s3 if exact file already exists in bucket

Tags: ruby, upload, amazon-s3, rubygems, last-modified

I want to periodically push images from a local directory to s3, but I don't want to overwrite files that were pushed previously that haven't changed since then. Here are the options I've considered:

1. Compare content-length. Drawback: A new version of the file could conceivably have the same content-length but be different.
2. Store the local modification info in s3 metadata to compare at push time. Drawback: This requires a POST and a PUT, doubling the uploaded data, adds overhead to the push task, and may be inconsistent when run from different machines.

There must be a better way. What am I missing?

P.S. I'm using the aws-s3 gem in a rake task.

Comment: Can't you store a hash of the images in S3's meta data when you are first uploading them, and then later on use the API that allows you to GET only the S3 headers, and compare the hash to a locally calculated hash for the current version of the file on the local system?

Comment: Thanks, Daan. The documentation made it sound like, due to a limitation in the public API, the metadata could only be added by getting the image, adding the metadata, and saving it again, resulting in a double upload of a sort. Which admittedly makes little sense. Maybe the limitation is gone or I read it wrong. I'll experiment and see...

Comment: That's true for adding meta data to existing files, but not at the initial upload stage, I think? :-)

Comment: S3 sends an e-tag with each get request, so you can just get the headers and check if the e-tag has changed against an md5 of the file.  The problem is, it's kinda slow IMO.  I'm looking for a better way, but don't think there is one.  Donno how to do it in ruby so I'm just adding a comment.

Answer (score -3):

a good tool is s3cmd with the --sync option. http://s3tools.org/s3cmd